# SQL get everything inside two symbol

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running into a problem where I have to extract the value inside two pipe, any suggestion would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Post your code, and a description of the problem.

Comment: Use something other than SQL since the number of items per row seems to be dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of a parse/split function and a CROSS Apply

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,[Desc] varchar(500))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'Purched Order 12345 ||COXFF6||'),
(2,'Purched Order 12345 ||COXFF6||,||COX888|| haha ||COX777||')

Select ID
      ,[Desc] = '||'+B.RetVal+'||'
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select * 
              From   [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](Replace('.'+A.[Desc],' ','.'),'||') 
              Where  RetVal not like '[.,]%'
             ) B
```

Returns

```
ID  Desc
1   ||COXFF6||
2   ||COXFF6||
2   ||COX888||
2   ||COX777||
```

---

The UDF if needed.  (logic can be migrated into the cross apply if can't use a UDF)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@String,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

googlethe [substring()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) and the [charIndex()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) functions.

The expression `charIndex('||', @desc)' will return the position of the first pair of pipes, so`2+charIndex('||', @desc)' is the position of the first character you want (the C), then to get the length, we need to subtract the position of the start from the position of the end. The end position is the charindex of the second pair of pipes. To get that use the last [optional] argument of charIndex function, which specifies where to start looking. If you set that as the position of the first pair of pipes, then charindex will find the position of the next (2nd) pair:  `charIndex('||', @desc, charIndex('||', @desc))`.  The length of the string to extract is the difference between them, (adjusted a bit)

```
declare @desc varchar(max) = 'Purchased Order ||COFX123412||'
Select 2+charIndex('||', @desc), -- position of start of COFX123412
    charIndex('||', @desc, charIndex('||', @desc)), -- pos of 2nd pair of pipes
    2+charIndex('||', @desc))-2-charIndex('||', @desc), -- Length  

    substring(@desc, 2+charIndex('||', @desc), 
         charIndex('||', @desc, 2+charIndex('||', @desc))- 
                      2-charIndex('||', @desc))
```

Comment: add some description please.